# Filter by string instead of select in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, meta-search

I have belongs_to and has_many assotiations between two models. By default, activeadmin using select input for it. But in my case, it's imposible - because I have a thousands items. 
When I trying change filter to

```
filter :item, as: :string
```

it says that

```
undefined method `item_id_contains' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::DeliveryTime:0x007fdd57f12db8>
```

What is the best way to do it right?

Answer (score 21):

ActiveAdmin uses [MetaSearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search), so you should be able to do

```
filter :items_<attribute>, as: :string
```

So in your case if the item has a name, you can do:

```
filter :items_name, as: :string
```

Comment: Isn't metasearch anymore, it's using Ransack(https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) but the answe is still valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Refer relation of models and the following code**

table = users
id, name, email

table = customers
id, name, user_id

user has_many customers

customer   belongs   user

USE filter :user_name, as: :string  instead of filter :user